# LEFT JOIN and NOT ISSET

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table:

```
Site:
id | name
 1 | google
 2 | stackoverflow
 3 | cnn.com

Confirm:
id | site_id | type // (type = 1, 2 or 3)
 1 | 1       | 2
 2 | 2       | 1
```

so and would like get Sites which is not added to table Confirm with type for example 1.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Site 
       LEFT JOIN Confirm 
            ON Site.id = Confirm.site_id
```

and what next?

Comment: WHERE confirm.site_id IS NULL

Comment: When you run your query, what do you notice about the records that you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A natural way to write this query is as a `NOT EXISTS` query:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM Sites s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Confirm c WHERE c.site_id = s.id AND type = 1);
```

It is almost a 1-1 translation of the problem statement:  "would like to get sites that are not added to `Confirm` with type = 1".

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you meant. But if you are in doubt about how to work with result sets from the database, look at this, maybe it can help you: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg